# Creating an HICON from a byte array in C++?

Tags: c++, icons

I have a PNG-encoded icon as a byte array in memory. What is the recommended way of creating an HICON object from this byte array?

---

Imaginary bonus points if you know a solution without ATL or GDI+... :)

Comment: create a stream out of it, and then load an icon from the stream...

Comment: how do i get an HICON from a stream?

Answer (score 4):

```
HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, dataSize);
LPVOID pImage = GlobalLock(hMem);
memcpy(pImage, pngData, dataSize);
GlobalUnlock(hMem);

ATL::CComPtr<IStream> pStream;
CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hMem, TRUE, &pStream);

Gdiplus::Bitmap *pBitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(pStream);
HICON YOUR_HICON = pBitmap->GetHICON();
```

Comment: also is there any way of doing it without ATL or GDI+?

Comment: Corrected: now you do have HICON. Without ATL or GDI+ — don't know Epaga, I'm not that hardcore anymore.

Comment: I don't see an Icon class in GDI+ - instead it would work with Gdiplus::Bitmap and then GetHICON.

Comment: Right! Of course. Icon is in .NET, but not in GDI+. Sorry. Yes, Gdiplus::Bitmap and then GetHICON should work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could do this with CreateBitmap and CreateIconIndirect, or maybe even just CreateIcon.  Don't ask me for code because I'm not really familiar with this low-level graphics stuff.