# Creating an icon from an array

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to load an icon from an array without success.

I have an array that contains a icon (.ico) in raw and I want to load it. The problem is that the function `CreateIconFromResourceEx` returns NULL.

About the icon I saved a .ico file in an array.

This is my code:

```
 HICON icon = NULL;

icon = CreateIconFromResourceEx(tray->icon, (DWORD)tray->fsize, TRUE, 0x30000, 32, 32, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR | LR_DEFAULTSIZE);

if (nid.hIcon) {
    DestroyIcon(nid.hIcon);
}

nid.hIcon = icon;
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, &nid);
```

where tray is:

```
struct tray {
unsigned char *icon;
int fsize;
struct tray_menu *menu;};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ["If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createiconfromresourceex)

Comment: ah sorry i forgot to add this information.. GetLastError return me 0

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379285/load-hicon-from-the-buffer-ico-file. It might not give you an immediate answer, but there may be valuable information anyway.

Comment: @GiGa you shouldn't edit your question with the answer, but post an answer to your own question instead

Comment: @Jabberwocky thanks.. i fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.. i need calculate the offset for the IMAGEDATA

```
offset = LookupIconIdFromDirectoryEx(tray->icon, TRUE, 32, 64, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
```

than

```
if (offset != 0) {
    icon = CreateIconFromResourceEx(tray->icon + offset, (DWORD)tray->fsize, TRUE, 0x30000, 32, 64, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
}
```